# Есть ли расширение для Visual Studio, чтобы автоматически загружать необходимое пространство имен С#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть ли расширение для Visual Studio, чтобы автоматически загружать необходимое пространство имен С#?

Comment: что значит "загружать необходимое пространство имен"?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @iKuzmychov
Ну вот допустим мы используем какой-то метод Linq, а расширение само пропишет Using System.Linq

Comment: так это невозможно, один и тот же метод может быть в разных библиотеках, какую именно тогда подключать? (ну или если только пользователю при этом дается выбор какую подключить в виде окошка с библиотеками)

Comment: @Pekor
В том же райдере есть такая штука и в VSCode для PHP есть

Comment: @Darl если вы работаете в Visual Studio, то достаточно поставить курсор в нужную позицию и нажать `Alt+Enter, Enter`, так как `Alt+Enter` вызывает меню быстродействия и в 99% случаев оно предложит вам добавить using, когда это необходимо, ну и это быстродействие можно выполнить с помощью нажатия `Enter`, так и получается комбинация из начала комментария

Comment: @iKuzmychov спасибо огромное

Comment: Возможно, удобнее будет комбинация `Ctrl`+`.` (или `ю` в русской раскладке). Можно мышкой это сделать. / А ещё можно надобавлять разных расширений в Студию из https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/

Comment: `Ctrl+.` на подчеркнутом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого не нужны расширения, достаточно нажать `Alt + Enter, Enter`:

1. Поставили курсор в нужное место:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Нажали `Alt + Enter`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Нажали `Enter`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.**

Как упомянул @AlexanderPetrov аналогично работает `Ctrl + ю, Enter`.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого не нужны плагины, это может и сама студия.

- Идем в настройки (<kbd>Средства</kbd> - <kbd>Параметры</kbd>)
- Открываем <kbd>Текстовый редактор</kbd> - <kbd>C#</kbd>, тут можем включить 2 функции:

| Раздел | Название | Описание |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IntelliSense | Отображать элементы из неимпортированных пространств имен | При написании кода, в подсказках, будут все доступные значения, включая те, `using` которых не были заданы, а при выборе элемента, `using` будет прописан автоматически. |
| Дополнительно | Добавить недостающие директивы using при вставке | При вставке текста, все `using` будут автоматически прописаны. |

Конечно, функции не без греха, но вполне удобные, особенно если еще и обучить студии своим кодом, чтобы ее нейросеть понимала, что лучше предлагать. В общем, можете еще полазить по настройкам, там много чего полезного есть, студия — это очень мощный комбайн)